# Undefined symbol ___ctzdi2

Tags: makefile, undefined-symbol

I am trying to install a debugger called [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on OSX 10.11.2.

While running make, I get the following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "___ctzdi2", referenced from:
      _doRegisterAllocation in libvex-x86-darwin.a(libvex_x86_darwin_a-host_generic_reg_alloc2.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
make[3]: *** [memcheck-x86-darwin] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may or may not work for you, as I am operating in the following environment:

- OS X 10.11.2,
- Xcode 7.3.1
- Custom built GCC 6.2.0 from source (which I am using instead of Xcode's clang compiler)
- The following patch file applied to valgrind-3.12.0:

  - https://gist.github.com/milljm/22e40e723fb9faf201b83197fc23b4a1

I received the same error as OP, until I used the following extra configure argument:

`./configure --enable-only64bit`